# How can I stop a loop with serial input

Tags: c++, loops, arduino-uno

How can I stop or exit from this loop using a serial input?
This is the simple code I've been using

```
#define stimulation 4
#define led 13

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  pinMode(stimulation,OUTPUT);       
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);    
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("Press any Key");
  while (!Serial.available()){}       
}

void loop() {    
  digitalWrite(stimulation, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  delay(20);                         
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);    
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(30);                          
}
```

I was looking for a serial input string to exit the loop

```
void loop() {    
  digitalWrite(stimulation, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  delay(20);                         
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);    
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(30);                          
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Put an `if(Serial.available()){....}` in your loop and read if something is available.

Comment: Thank you! I actually did this adding a long delay.

Answer (score 0):

As your code will work without the serial monitor, you can try this snippet:

```
void setup() {
  /* other codes */
  Serial.begin(57600);
  int numTries = 0;
  while (!Serial.available()){
    if( ++numTries >= 10) break;
    delay(100);
  }       
}
```

**Edited:** I was assuming that you got stuck during the initial setup stage when `Serial` monitor don't respond. Since you like to blink the LED only once, you can do like so using `static` keyword. When a variable is declared as static, space for it gets allocated for the lifetime of the program.

```
void loop() {    
  static bool done = false; // will initialize only once
  digitalWrite(stimulation, HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  delay(20);                         
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);    
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(30);
  if(!done && Serial.available()) {
     Serial.println("Stimulation Done :)");
     done = true;
  }                          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define stimulation 4
#define led 13
unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned long currentMillis;
const unsigned long stimTime = 20*60000;  // Stimulation Time (60s = 60000ms)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(stimulation,OUTPUT);       
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);   // force laser OFF before starting 
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("Standby:");
  Serial.println("Press any key to start stimulation");
  while (!Serial.available()){}     // do absolutely nothing until serial input received
  startMillis = millis();           // time (ms) when input received
  Serial.println("Now you wait 20min :)");       
}  
void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();         // time (ms) beginning of the loop
  if (currentMillis - startMillis <= stimTime) {  
  digitalWrite(stimulation, HIGH);  // Laser ON
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);          // Internal Led ON 
  delay(20);                        // Keep laser ON for 20ms
  digitalWrite(stimulation, LOW);   // Laser OFF
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);           // Internal Led OFF
  delay(30);                        // Keep laser OFF for 30ms
}   
  else {                            // After 20min do nothing (stop stimulation)
    }                          
}
```

Comment: See my edited answer. I miss construe your question earlier.

Comment: yep I like it, but since I know exactly the time I have to loop I ended up using the updated code. My only problem is that every time I want to re-run the code I have to upload the sketch. I was thinking maybe to use different stages.